# Injecting a service generic in the class it is being injected in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I have an `ILogger` interface and an `ILogger<T>` which is the one that is actually implemented and inherits from the former. I have registered the `ILogger<T>` interface in `Autofac` and it works fine, but I have to ask for an `ILogger<T>`. Is it possible to make it so that when:

```
class MyService
{
    public MyService(ILogger logger)...
}
```

`logger` is actually `ILogger<MyService>`

Comment: You do `public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger)`. But that seems to be like you have a weird logging class

Comment: Can you not register it for `ILogger` as well?  I doubt Autofac will automatically use your `ILogger<T>` registration just because it extends that interface.

Comment: `builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(SomeInstance1<>))
  .As(typeof(IGenericInterface<>))`

Answer (score 0):

So registration first: from the [docs](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components)

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(NHibernateRepository<>))
   .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
   .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

So your code

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(LoggerService<>))
   .As(typeof(ILogger<>))
   .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Here is my working sample:

```
using System;
using Autofac;          

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(LoggerService<>))
               .As(typeof(ILogger<>))
               .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        
        var container = builder.Build();
        
        var obj = container.Resolve<ILogger<MyService>>();
        var obj2 = container.Resolve<ILogger<OtherService>>();
        
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Log());
        Console.WriteLine(obj2.Log());
    }
}

public interface ILogger<T>
{
    string Log();
}

public class LoggerService<T> : ILogger<T>
{
    public string Log()
    {
        return typeof(T).Name;
    }
}

public class MyService
{
    
}

public class OtherService
{
    
}
```

Outputs:

> Hello World
>
> MyService
>
> OtherService

Comment: I already have that working, what I want is being able to do `container.Resolve<ILogger>();` and get the proper `ILogger<T>` where `T` is the class calling `Resolve`.

Comment: It is not dependency injection if you are calling Resolve..... in your constructor you would simply do `public MyService(ILogger<MyService> myServiceLogger)` but again it seems weird that you are tying a cross cutting concern to a serivce. It seems a bit weird...

Comment: If you see my question, what I want to do is `public MyService(ILogger logger)` and have `logger` actually be `ILogger<MyService>`.